# Not able to mount azure file share into local RHEL7 VM

Tags: azure-storage, symlink, rhel

I want to mount(symlink) from  Azure file share to a local RHEL7 VM . I am using the following command

```
mount -t cifs //<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<share-name>  /mymountpoint -o vers=3.0,username=<storage-acc-name>,password=<pwd>,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp,mfsymlinks
```

but getting the following error

> mount error(13): Permission denied
>
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

```
`The dmesg | tail gives the following log
[root@googleapps ~]# dmesg | tail
[98383.619149] fs/cifs/smb2misc.c: SMB2 data length 0 offset 0
[98383.619151] fs/cifs/smb2misc.c: SMB2 len 77
[98383.619163] fs/cifs/transport.c: cifs_sync_mid_result: cmd=1 mid=1 state=4
[98383.619168] Status code returned 0xc0000022 STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[98383.619175] fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code -1073741790 to POSIX err -13
[98383.619177] fs/cifs/misc.c: Null buffer passed to cifs_small_buf_release
[98383.619181] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[98383.619185] fs/cifs/connect.c: CIFS VFS: leaving cifs_get_smb_ses (xid = 59) rc = -13
[98383.619297] fs/cifs/connect.c: CIFS VFS: leaving cifs_mount (xid = 58) rc = -13
[98383.619300] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13`
```

Comment: did anyone having any solution? because its needed urgently to be fixed.I could not point out why this problem is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Symlink option then manually linking it afterwards. I did a quick test on my machine, a RHEL V7 (Brand new for testing) on Azure, and linked a file share with it using the following steps:

**1**- Manually create the mount point dir, then run the following:

```
sudo yum install cifs-utils
sudo mount -t cifs //USERNAME.file.core.windows.net/FILESHARE ~/mountpoint/ -o vers=3.0,username=<>,password=<>,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp
```

Then try using the symlink afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. Read most of the forums tried all in the end found that password used by me was wrong and it has to be SSH key which is generated with storage account. I got hint to this by using trouble shooting script by Azure support. 
You can find this script here :
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Troubleshooting-tool-for-02184089

Bash script found here can be used to go through series of probable issues and will give you a fair idea of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will get `Status code returned 0xc0000022 STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` if you do not have the proper "Public network access" setting.

Set this setting to "All networks" or add your Server IP/CIDR to the firewall exclusion list.

[image]